# Validação de pedido via jQuery, Json

Tags: jquery, json, validação

Quero fazer uma função que ao cliente digitar seu pedido ele é verificado se existe no banco ou se é um pedido inválido. E quero retornar isso via Ajax, mas eu nunca mexi com Ajax, alguém saberia como fazer?

**Função**

```
    public function verificaAction() {

            #Recebe o Pedido Postado
            $increment_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ordertxt');

            #Conecta banco de dados 
            $ordertexto = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $increment_id); 

            #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, envia o form, se for menor da o error
            if ($ordertexto[0]['increment_id'] == $increment_id) { 
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('increment_id' => 'Número invalido' ));
    }
}
```

Não sei onde, mas acho que estou fazendo alguma verificação errada no IF.

**jQuery Ajax tentativa**

```
$j("#ordertxt").focus(function() {}).blur(function() { 
    ordertxt = $j("#ordertxt").val(); 
         $j.ajax({ 
            url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contato/index/verifica') ?>', 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
            if (ordertexto == 1) {
                $j("#msg_pedido").html("Esse número de pedido não existe!");
            } else if (ordertexto == 0) {
                $j("#msg_pedido").html("Esse existe!");
            }
        },
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos erros que você está cometendo na sua call AJAX é que você não está passando o valor que foi pego no input `$j("#ordertxt")` através do data do ajax

```
$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 url: "some.php",
 **data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }**
 dataType: 'json'
})
```

Outro é que você está esquecendo de pegar o retorno da sua requisição através do parâmetro da success function:

```
 success: function (result)
```

Você pode tentar usar esse exemplo abaixo, talvez o retorno não seja exatamente como coloquei, pois como você não colocou o if completo fica dificil saber como será tratado o resutlad dessa requisição, mas você pode dá um `console.log(data)` e acessar as informações do melhor jeito, acredito que assim você conseguirá obter o que você precisa

> No exemplo abaixo eu estou usando um [shorthand](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) para o AJAX do Jquery

```js
$j("#ordertxt").focus(function() {}).blur(function() { 
    ordertxt = $j("#ordertxt").val(); 
    
 // Enviando a data pelo post
var posting = $.post('<?= Mage::getUrl('contato/index/verifica') ?>', {'ordertxt': orderTxt }); 
  // verificando resultado
  // o parâmetro da função é o resultado retornado pela sua action
  posting.done(function( data ) {
      if(parseInt(data) === 1){
        $j("#msg_pedido").html("Esse número de pedido não existe!");
      } else if (parseInt(data) === 0) {
          $j("#msg_pedido").html("Esse existe!");
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ah e eu acredito que seria melhor você usar um GET invés de POST, já que você só quer obter uma informação dá consulta do banco, esse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886013/http-verbs-when-to-use-get-post-put-delete) explica melhor sobre os verbos HTTP e quando usá-los